# Django - uploading image to database raises IntegrityError

Tags: django, django-forms, django-views, django-models

I'm trying to allow users to upload an image. When users are first created, they are given a unique ID / primary key. When users upload an image, I want to save that image in a folder depending on what the users unique ID is. For example, if the users unique ID is 1, I want to save it in

```
1/uploadedPhotos/imageName
```

This is my model:

```
def get_file_path(instance, filename):
    return os.path.join('%s/uploadedPhotos' % instance.user_id, filename)

class UserImages(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    photo = models.ImageField(upload_to=get_file_path)
```

and this is my form:

```
class UploadImageForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = UserImages
        fields = ['photo']
```

and this is my view:

```
def uploadImageView(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = UploadImageForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            # file is saved
            form.save()
            return redirect('/')
    else:
        form = UploadImageForm()

    return render(request, 'uploadImagePage.html', {'uploadImageForm': form})
```

The URL which calls the uploadImageView view is /uploadImage/. when I go to that URL and upload an image using the uploadImageForm, it gives an error saying:

```
IntegrityError at /uploadImage/

null value in column "user_id" violates not-null constraint
DETAIL:  Failing row contains (1, null, None/uploadedPhotos/imageName.png).
```

and the traceback leads back to the

```
form.save()
```

line in my uploadImageView. What am I doing wrong to cause this error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `UserImages` model requires `user` but your form `UploadImageForm` is asking only asking for `photo`. You need to set `user`, try something like this:

```
def uploadImageView(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = UploadImageForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            # file is saved
            instance = form.save(commit=False)
            instance.user = request.user
            instance.save()
            return redirect('/')
    else:
        form = UploadImageForm()

    return render(request, 'uploadImagePage.html', {'uploadImageForm': form})
```

Answer (score 1):

```
obj = form.save(commit=False)
obj.user = request.user
obj.save()
```

Answer (score 1):

You must extract user from request.user and add it to form data.